# how i can limit size image selected

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My problem's  the consumption memory, I need limit size the image selected.

**Edit**

I don't need to resize image after load, I can resize image using

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, (int) 80, (int) 80, true);
```

I need to prevent user select images > 5 MB

**my code**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
    }
}
```

*Limit size folder not it's the better option.*

**SOLUTION**

I solved my problem with this method:

```
public boolean MaxSizeImage(String imagePath) {
    boolean temp = false;
    File file = new File(imagePath);
    long length = file.length();

    if (length < 1500000) // 1.5 mb
        temp = true;

    return temp;
}
```

if you need imagePath, you can use this method

```
 public String getImagePath(Uri uri){
     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
     document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":")+1);
     cursor.close();

     cursor = getContentResolver().query(
             android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
             null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
     cursor.close();

     return path;
 }
```

Comment: I don't think you can limit the size when you are picking it, but you can crop it afterwards or scale or compress the Bitmap.

Comment: Use BitmapFactory.options, im pretty sure then you can set resolution before its loaded into memory so you know what your working with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This Hackro :D

First:

```
public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
private void takePictureFromGalleryOrAnyOtherFolder() 
{
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),PICK_IMAGE);
}
```

Then:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
           if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
               //Now you have imagePath do whatever you want to do now
             }//end of inner if
         }//end of outer if
  }

public String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
    Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {
            // Will return "image:x*"
            String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(contentUri);
            // Split at colon, use second item in the array
            String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];
            // where id is equal to
            String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, sel, new String[] { id }, null);
        } else {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
                    projection, null, null, null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String path = null;
    try {
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        path = cursor.getString(column_index).toString();
        cursor.close();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return path;
}
```

Comment: the method getRealPathFromURI it's very helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you care about memory consumption, I think you can use `Fresco` image library developed by Facebook. In its docs you would find:

> Fresco is a powerful system for displaying images in Android
>   applications. It takes care of image loading and display so you don't
>   have to.
>
> Fresco's image pipeline will load images from the network, local
>   storage, or local resources. *To save data and CPU, it has three levels
>   of cache; two in memory and another in internal storage*.
>
> Fresco's Drawees show a placeholder for you until the image has loaded
>   and automatically show to the image when it arrives. *When the image
>   goes off-screen, it automatically releases its memory.*

Then in **Features** section you would found:

> ### Memory
>
> A decompressed image - an Android Bitmap - takes up a lot of memory.
>   This leads to more frequent runs of the Java garbage collector. This
>   slows apps down. The problem is especially bad without the
>   improvements to the garbage collector made in Android 5.0.
>
> On Android 4.x and lower, Fresco puts images in a special region of
>   Android memory. It also makes sure that images are automatically
>   released from memory when they're no longer shown on screen. This lets
>   your application run faster - and suffer fewer crashes.
>
> Apps using Fresco can run even on low-end devices without having to
>   constantly struggle to keep their image memory footprint under
>   control.

Official site: http://frescolib.org/

GitHub: https://github.com/facebook/fresco

Article: [Introducing Fresco: A new image library for Android](https://code.facebook.com/posts/366199913563917/introducing-fresco-a-new-image-library-for-android/)

It seems to be fitted to your needs. That's why I need to write an answer about it.

Hope it help

Answer (score 1):

use something like this to load the image at the memory youd like it to be, this is using a file path, there is methods for streams also check out [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html)

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
String imageType = options.outMimeType;
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,512,256);//512 and 256 whatever you want as scale
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath,options);
```

helper method

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
    final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
    final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

    // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
    // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
    // requested height and width.
    inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
}

return inSampleSize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to fetch images. There's a resize option when you call and get images, that could help with size. You'd probably be limited to "one size fits all" for images though. It also makes a lot of additional features simple when loading images, such as placeholders, error images when your image doesn't load, and a few other utilities.

Here's an example request from the link:

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

Comment: in this case does not work, I have to prevent users selections images > 5MB

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do that while selecting an image, but you can check size of file after select image.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        String imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);

        int sizeInBytes = 0;
        int MAX_BYTES = your_number_of_bytes;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
                sizeInBytes = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
        } else {
                sizeInBytes = bitmap.getByteCount();
        }

        if(sizeInBytes > MAX_BYTES) {
                // If the image is higher than max number of bytes, start all over again.
        }

        }
    }
}
```